# Intelligent searching with mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, search, mongodb-query

I am using phalcon with mongodb. I have the following `document` in collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("547c8b6f7d30dd522b522255"),
"title" : "Test vacancy",
"slug" : "test-vacancy",
"location" : "the-netherlands",
"contract" : "fixed",
"function" : "Test vacancy",
"short_description" : "gdfsgfds",
"description" : "fdsafsdgfsdgdfa",
"promo_text" : "gfdsgdfs",
"company_name" : "gfdsgfsd",
"hits" : 36,
"updated_at" : 1.42685e+09,
}
```

In `controller` I am fetching all results by searched phase/query. For example I put `example` word and output will be all posts with `example` word in `description` or `title` or `short_desc` etc.  Everything is correct but I want sort these posts in specific order. I mean if `query` will be same as `title`, this post should be first. Now it is somewhere below.

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: MongoDB has something called FTS which will sort by relevancy which is what you are asking for

Comment: Though if you are asking for specific sorting by field weighting you might find other FTS techs better